# Easiest/cheapest way to convert C# code on home PC to a web service?

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I have lots of code snippets on my pc that do a whole bunch of cool things in C# (not asp.net, these are mainly console apps). I store all my results in a mysql database on my home PC.

What is the best way forward for converting this all into an online web service with login portal etc? My asp.net knowledge is limited, so I may have to hire someone for this. Trouble is I know C# and PHP, but no asp.net!

Is cloud hosting recommended versus dedicated server versus normal hosting? The database will be several gigabytes with a growth rate of 150 megabytes per day.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me i'd create a simple [asp.net mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) app with forms authentication. The learning curve is much easier than web forms, especially for making end points/web services, i'm assuming you don't require automated discoverability/automation that you'd get from SOAP services.

Of course with web forms you can create an asmx web service but i just much prefer mvc! Go have a read, its really easy, you just need to no a few bits to get started, then its all c#, html/css javascript, no horrible life cycles!